# Why am i getting no output from this

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have to make a function that returns a char pointer to a sub string. The sub string is given to us by two pointers one for the start of the sub string and one for the end. This substring is smaller than the original string that start is pointing to.

```
char* get_substring(char* start, char* end)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char stringtest[] = "ABCDE";
    char* pos1 = stringtest;
    char* pos2 = stringtest+3;
    char* test = get_substring(pos1, pos2);
    printf("%s", test);
    return 0;
}


char* get_substring(char* start, char* end)
{
    int i = &end - &start;
    char* buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    for(int x=0; x < i; x++)
    {
        *(buffer+x) = *(start+x);
    }
    *(buffer+i) = '\0';
    return buffer;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: any error  showing ?

Comment: You are assigning the content of `sringtest[0]` to `pos1` and the content of `stringtest[3]` to `pos2`. What you really want is `char *pos1=stringtest` and `char *pos2=stringtest+3`.

Comment: If you then print `pos1` and `pos2` you will see they are `A` and `D` respectively.

Comment: Please edit the Title of your problem. Expand "this" with something meaningful. Best of luck

Comment: `get_substring()` is returning a pointer to a local variable, which invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Function `get_substring()` returns the address of a local variable `buffer`. This is undefined behavior because the memory allocated for `buffer` will be gone when the function returns to the calling parent. Use `malloc()` instead.

Comment: Parameters `start` and `end` are character pointers. The addresses of these pointers will not necessarily mean 3 addresses apart. You should calculate the length by using the addresses they point to. Change to `int i = end - start`.

Comment: @alvits to use malloc in this occasion would i do char* buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);

and then in the for loop change buffer[x] to (buffer + x)?

Comment: Yes. Although you don't need to cast the return value of malloc. You can keep using the `buffer[x]` notation in addition to using the `*(buffer + x)` notation.

Comment: @alvits when i try to compile it is giving me errors on my line
char* buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*15);

sorry quite new to using malloc and havent been able to get it to work cleanly yet. cheers for the help

Comment: You need to include `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @alvits hahaha yea i just realised that and put it in. Ive changed it all to the new buffer like so *(buffer +i) = '\0'; but im still getting no output. I have changed the way im calling get_substring to get_substring(&stringtest[0], &stringtest[3]) but still no results any ideas?

Comment: Can you update the post with all the changes please?

Comment: Try `get_substring(teststring, teststring + 3);`. And don't forget `int i = end - start`.

Comment: Shouldn't `buffer[u] = *(start+x);` be `buffer[x] = *(start+x);`?

Comment: @alvits ye got it with changing the end - start

cheers for the help man

Comment: @alvits i have heard you have to use free() when using malloc is that true in this case?

Comment: When you no longer need the memory, you need to free it. Make it a habit so you won't leak memory when you write bigger codes.

Comment: @alvits so do i do it after i return the buffer im guessing or do i not need to as it is in its own function and the function is relatively short

Comment: @C.Evenhuis You're totally wrong; firstly, C doesn't support the `new` operator, secondly, you're confusing C++ and C# syntax; in C(++), if you want an array, you put the brackets after the name, not the type: `char arr[10]`, not `char[10] arr`.

Comment: Try `int i = end - start;` in the new code. If that did not work, try `ptrdiff_t i = end - start;`

Comment: @brnpls: Please don't update the code in your question with fixes from comments. You just end up rendering not only the comments and answers, but also your question, meaningless.

Comment: @brnpls - the print statement still needs it. you free it after printing.

Comment: @szczurcio Oops, apparently C# filter wasn't active and I wasn't paying attention. I had mistaken it for C# unsafe code.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `char pos1 = stringtest[0];` you are copying the first char into a new variable `pos1`. When you take the address of `pos1`, you are using the address of that new variable with the copy. What you need to do is use the address of the char inside the string by doing something like `&stringtest[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Provide semicolon in `buffer[10]`

`char buffer[10];`

Comment: This should be a comment. `:` is the colon. You probably meant to say `;` which is a semi-colon. And if this was not there, the compiler will emit an error and the code will not compile.